# java.lang.NullPointerException when creating a StatefulKnowledgeSession with JPAKnowledgeService

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, drools

I am trying to get `JPAKnowledgeService` work with my Spring Boot application. For this I have followed the instructions from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.1/javadocs/org/drools/persistence/jpa/JPAKnowledgeService.html).

My `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit  name="org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.SessionInfo</class>
        <class>org.drools.persistence.info.WorkItemInfo</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.jndi.class" value="bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username"  value="username"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password"  value="password"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.BTMTransactionManagerLookup" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I haven't defined transaction boundaries and I had to `exclude` `hibernate-ja-2.0-api` from `drools-persistence-jpa` to use 2.1 that is provided by Spring itself.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-persistence-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Upon calling `newStatefulKnowledgeSession` like this:

```
Environment env = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newEnvironment();
env.set( EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "org.jbpm.persistence.jpa" ) );
env.set( EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager() );

KieSession kSession = JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(kieBase, null, env);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory' defined in class path resource [org/hasancansaral/jpaknowledgeservicesample/JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession]: Factory method 'JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176) [spring-boot-1.4.4.RELEASE.jar:1.4.4.RELEASE]
    at org.hasancansaral.jpaknowledgeservicesample.JPAKnowledgeServiceSample.main(JPAKnowledgeServiceSample.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.kie.internal.runtime.StatefulKnowledgeSession]: Factory method 'JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:185) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121) ~[kie-internal-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.hasancansaral.jpaknowledgeservicesample.JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration.JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory(JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hasancansaral.jpaknowledgeservicesample.JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a75599c4.CGLIB$JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.hasancansaral.jpaknowledgeservicesample.JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a75599c4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6a4558.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.hasancansaral.jpaknowledgeservicesample.JPAKnowledgeServiceConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a75599c4.JPAKnowledgeServiceFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:171) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.drools.persistence.jta.JtaTransactionManager.getStatus(JtaTransactionManager.java:273) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.AbstractPersistenceContextManager.getApplicationScopedEntityManager(AbstractPersistenceContextManager.java:78) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContextManager.getApplicationScopedPersistenceContext(JpaPersistenceContextManager.java:55) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    at org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.<init>(SingleSessionCommandService.java:103) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.5.0.Final.jar:6.5.0.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

I also have a sample repo to recreate this error that can be found [here](https://github.com/hasancansaral/spring-boot-jpaknowledgeservice-sample). Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to invoke (via reflection) a nonexistent constructor at buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:171).

Comment: Put the logs of JtaTransactionManager in DEBUG mode and see if you find something.

Comment: It turned out to be I was missing `jndi.properties` with line `java.naming.factory.initial=bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use jndi.properties file in the root of your class path to point java to use bitrnix as JNDI provider so it can bind transaction manager into JNDI so then JtaTransactionManager can look it up

create new file: src/main/resources/jndi.properties with following content:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using JTA transactions, try with this property:

```
 <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform" />
```

Comment: It didn't help. It turned out to be I was missing `jndi.properties` with line `java.naming.factory.initial=bitronix.tm.jndi.BitronixInitialContextFactory`.